# NetBeans importing classes package problems

Tags: class, netbeans, import, package

I have created a class in Java that I need to import into NetBeans and use in a GUI.  What I have done so far is add the jar file containing the classes to the library in my project.  I can look inside the jar file and see the classes I need inside the .  I have looked around online and know that the best to way import these classes is to move them to another package that isn't the .

My problem is that I do not know how to do this.  I saw that I can create a package in netbeans, but it is gray when it appears and I can't seem to do anything with it.  I basically have no idea how to create packages that I can use to import classes  If someone could please walk me through step by step I would greatly appreciate it.  I have looked at the other posts on this site and other places online, but they seem to skip over somethings I am not sure about.  My teacher didn't mention anything about packages either, so I am really in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your source files (`*.java`) in your project's `src` folder, then use [refactoring](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring) to change the package.

Right-click your java file, then select `Refactor > Move` and type your new package name.

Comment: I have a question though.  I thought it was working, but it doesn't quite seem to work yet.  Can a class be imported if it is in a package in the source package, or does it have to be in the Library?  Mine is in a new package in the Source Package.  It doesn't seem to be able to recognize it.

Comment: never again...apparently restarting the program and computer seemed to do the trick.  thanks again